# What does Ctrl+C do in Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, copy-paste

Does anyone know what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> do in Ubuntu Terminal? Since they don't copy/paste, is there any particular functionality to these buttons?

When I press those shortcut, it writes `^C` and `^V`.

I'm worried because I was working on a little PHP program, and I'm editing from terminal. I'm a control freak, and I would hate if those buttons did something I'm not aware of.

Comment: This question belongs to http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: More appropriate site for this question: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is abort in UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C):

  > In POSIX systems, the sequence causes the active program to receive a SIGINT signal. If the program does not specify how to handle this condition, it is terminated. Typically a program which does handle a SIGINT will still terminate itself, or at least terminate the task running inside it.
- [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in UNIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-V):

  > Unix interactive terminals use Control-V to mean "the next character should be treated literally" (the mnemonic here is "v is for verbatim"). This allows a user to insert a literal Control-C or Control-H or similar control characters that would otherwise be handled by the terminal.

This is in the shell and it's just defaults. When running a program, it is dependent on the program what these do!

Comment: The signal is SIGINT.

Comment: Pedantry: Since there is a SIGABRT that signals an "abort", I would change "is abort in UNIX" to "is 'interrupt' in UNIX".

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends a terminating signal to the current process running.

To copy or paste in the terminal, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, but I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> stops whatever program you are running.

If you want to copy or paste using keyboard shortcuts, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> respectively.

Comment: Ctrl+C don't stop "what ever program you are running" it's false, it just send a SIGINT signal to the process on the foreground. If the process is not defined to stop on SIGINT, the process stay alive.